# How to avoid jasmine throw the error: XXX has already been spied upon?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

**Background**

I have two Case need to test

- should form valid when going to next page

  1. set form valid is true
  2. call `goToNextPage()`
  3. expect result is truthy
- should form valid when filling out option info then going to next page

  1. set form valid is true
  2. **open option info block**
  3. **ensure the form is valid**
  4. call `goToNextPage()`
  5. expect result is truthy

---

**Question**

In step 3 of the second test, It will throw an Error When I spy a property by `spyOnProperty` more than two times

spyOnProperty(myObject, 'myPropertyName').and.returnValue(...);

> Error: 'myPropertyName' has already been spied upon

**I refer to the solutions of the past few years and write a temporary solution below. Are there any easier ways to solve this now?**

- [angular-unit-testing-with-jasmine-how-to-remove-or-modify-spyon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28821511/7291379)
- [insertspyon-2-times-jquery-value-to-input-during-jasmine-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084022/insertspyon-2-times-jquery-value-to-input-during-jasmine-tests)

  - [Jasmine spyOn with multiple returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707283/jasmine-spyon-with-multiple-returns)

---

**My Temp Solution**

- set `jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);`
- cache the first spy and use it later

```js
class SamplePageHelper {

  private respyHelper = new JasmineRespyHelper();

  constructor(
    public samplePage: SamplePage
  ) {

  }

  fakeValid() {
    // spyOnProperty(this.samplePage, 'isValid').and.returnValue(true);
    this.respyHelper.spyOnProperty(this.samplePage, 'isValid').and.returnValue(true);
  }



}
// helper
class JasmineRespyHelper {

  private cacheList = new Map();

  constructor() {
    jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);
  }

  spyOnProperty < T > (object: T, property: keyof T, accessType ? : 'get' | 'set'): jasmine.Spy {
    const objectKey = object.constructor.toString().substring(0, 15);
    const cacheKey = `${objectKey}_${property}_${accessType || ''}`;
    //
    let spy = this.cacheList.get(cacheKey);
    const isNoCached = !spy;
    if (isNoCached) {
      spy = spyOnProperty(object, property, accessType);
      this.cacheList.set(cacheKey, spy);
    }
    //
    return spy;
  }
}
```

---

**Online Sample**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jsamine-respy?file=src/test/sample.spec.ts

```js
describe('demo (no TestBed):', () => {

  let samplePage;
  let samplePageHelper;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    samplePage = new SamplePage();
    samplePageHelper = new SamplePageHelper(samplePage);
  })

  it('shoud valid when write option fields then go to next page', () => {
    samplePageHelper.fakeValid();
     //
    samplePage.openOptionFieldBlock();
    //  new option field value will trigger form validator

    // ensure `goToNextPage()` can be executed needs to specify isValid to true again
    // Error: isValid has already been spied upon
    samplePageHelper.fakeValid();


    const isSuccess = samplePage.goToNextPage();

    expect(isSuccess).toBeTruthy();
  })

  it('shout valid when go to next page', () => {
    samplePageHelper.fakeValid();

    const isSuccess = samplePage.goToNextPage();

    expect(isSuccess).toBeTruthy();
  })
});


class SamplePage {

  private formService = new FormServiceStub();

  get isValid() {
    // trigger form field's validator
    // real code like this : formService.validationAll(); 
    return this.formService.valiationAll();
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  openOptionFieldBlock() {
    if (this.isValid) {
      // do someting 
    }
  }

  goToNextPage() {
    if (this.isValid) {
      // do someting

      const isSuccess = true;
      return isSuccess;
    }

    return false;
  }

  showOptionFields() {
    return true;
  }


}


// stub
class FormServiceStub {
  valiationAll() {
    // it's have more codition in real code , return true for the demo
    return true;
  }
}

class SamplePageHelper {

  constructor(
    public samplePage: SamplePage
  ) {

  }

  fakeValid() {
    spyOnProperty(this.samplePage, 'isValid').and.returnValue(true);
  }



}
```

Comment: One you've spied on it once, you can just change its behaviour directly: `myObject.myPropertyName.and...`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is this your mean https://jsfiddle.net/hdn3afvj/?

Comment: please provide some source code which you wanna test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine SpyOn same method more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200532/jasmine-spyon-same-method-more-than-once)

Comment: Has a new solution after two years ? It's a same way as my jasmineRespyHelper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular unit testing with Jasmine: how to remove or modify spyOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821511/angular-unit-testing-with-jasmine-how-to-remove-or-modify-spyon)